# While connecting Tableau to Azure Synapase via oauth getting error "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: oauth, tableau-api, azure-synapse, tableau-desktop

I am trying to add Azure synapse dataset in Tableau Desktop 2021.1 and have to use oauth login. I get redirected to login page and when I enter password, I get redirected to http://localhost:5000/callback page and following error occurs. Trying to figure out if this error is related to Tableau cannot be able to find SSL certificate from microsftonline? What is the root cause of this issue?

“An error occurred while communicating with the data source
Authentication failed.
Error Code: 84223ADA
SSLHandshakeException
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target”

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot and try to find the similar error and query on any supported document, but there is only one article I have found which is related to same error.

You should try to add oauth2 link to the bypass or exception list for SSL inspection. This is because Tableau Desktop may be unable to connect to oauth2 because of SSL inspection (or HTTPS interception).

Please refer https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/Error-SSLHandshakeException-PKIX-path-building-failed-When-Connecting-to-Google-Analytics for more details.